# Why do "gem" and "sudo gem" have different installation directories?

Tags: rubygems, rvm

I remember I used `gem install rails` to install Rails, but today when I want to install another gem, by typing

```
gem install ruby-recaptcha
```

it fails, saying:

> You don't have write permissions into the ...

Then I found my `gem environment` and `sudo gem environment` have different results:

For `gem environment`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-darwin11.0.1]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/hx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/hx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/hx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/hx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
     - /Users/hx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :gempath => ["/Users/hx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290"]
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

For `sudo gem environment`:

```
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-darwin11.0.1]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/hx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/hx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/hx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/hx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /Users/hx/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :gempath => ["/Users/hx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290"]
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Noticed that the installation directory is different. So when I use `gem`, I do not have permissions (I don't know why I suddenly lose the permission). But when I use `sudo gem`, the gem is not installed into the right place. How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you install RVM? Did you use `sudo` when doing so?

Comment: I think I did not use sudo when install rvm... everything goes fine then but I don't know why it suddenly require permissions....

Comment: by the way. the gem folder in under /Users/hx/.rvm/...how can I need permission??..is there any way to change the permission requirement of that folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RVM uses environment variables to configure rubygems - the `gem` command, basically if you have user installation (`~/.rvm`) you should not need to use to call any commands with `sudo`, especially `gem` - that if worked would install rail as `root` user in your home directory, making it impossible for you to manage your files ... if you have any good reasons to use `sudo` - use `rvmsudo` instead - but really you should not have that need, especially to install gems.

If you want to have some commands available in your system (like `gist`) you can use `rvm wrapper` and link generated binary in `/usr/bin`

to fix permissions in your home:

```
sudo chown $USER: ~/.rvm
sudo chmod u+rw ~/.rvm
```

Comment: yes。。I used it chmod to change permission....but I'm still curious why I suddenly lose the permission..ok...never mind...thX!!!!