# not able to use gem even after bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems

I am creating a [dashing](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing) project, on a Linux machine.

When I do `bundle install`, it installs all the gems, but when I try to use the gem, it gives me an error and suggests to do `bundle install` again.

The commands and output follow:

```
saurabh@my-linux:~/beacon$ bundle install

Using addressable 2.3.8
Using execjs 2.0.2
Using json 1.8.3
Using autoprefixer-rails 6.0.3
Using backports 3.6.6
Using sass 3.2.19
Using bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.2
Using buftok 0.2.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using daemons 1.2.3
Using rack 1.5.5
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using rufus-scheduler 2.0.24
Using rack-protection 1.5.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sinatra 1.4.6
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using sinatra-contrib 1.4.6
Using hike 1.2.3
Using sprockets 2.10.2
Using eventmachine 1.0.8
Using thin 1.6.4
Using thor 0.18.1
Using dashing 1.3.4
Using unf_ext 0.0.7.1
Using unf 0.1.4
Using domain_name 0.5.25
Using equalizer 0.0.10
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using faraday 0.9.2
Using http-cookie 1.0.2
Using http-form_data 1.0.1
Using http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Using http 0.9.8
Using memoizable 0.4.2
Using naught 1.1.0
Using netrc 0.7.9
Using rest_client 1.8.3
Using simple_oauth 0.3.1
Using twitter 5.15.0
Using bundler 1.10.6
Updating files in vendor/cache
Bundle complete! 5 Gemfile dependencies, 44 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

saurabh@my-linux:~/beacon$ bundle show dashing

/usr/lib/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dashing-1.3.4

saurabh@my-linux:~/beacon$ /usr/lib/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dashing-1.3.4/bin/dashing start

/usr/lib/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dashing-1.3.4/lib/dashing/cli.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- thor (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dashing-1.3.4/lib/dashing/cli.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dashing-1.3.4/bin/dashing:6:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dashing-1.3.4/bin/dashing:6

saurabh@my-linux:~/beacon$ dashing start

Could not find addressable-2.3.8 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

saurabh@my-linux:~/beacon$ /usr/lib/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dashing-1.3.4/bin/dashing start

Could not find addressable-2.3.8 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't abuse bold text; It's as bad as writing everything in uppercase. Instead use a little more commentary and format the commands you typed in the same as the output received.

Comment: @theTinMan: Edited, Thanks.

Comment: `/use/lib/lib` is very suspicious and likely the problem. There should only be a single `lib`. I suspect you forced the path instead of allowing the install go where it knew it should. Ruby and gem could also be confused as a result. Perhaps a starting question should be "How do I install Ruby correctly?"

Answer (score 0):

sound like 2 options:

1. you didn't restarted your server after `bundle install`, please do.
2. you used `sudo` to install the gems so they installed to all linux users as `root` so bottom line they really not in your source path, read more about it here:
   [Why do "gem" and "sudo gem" have different installation directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065496/why-do-gem-and-sudo-gem-have-different-installation-directories)

Comment: It isn't necessarily to restart a Linux server after installing gems. Restarting individual apps might help but generally they would not have been started until after the `bundle install` succeeds.